# Select tag Json array elements

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<select ng-model="MyCtrl.getCargo().handler.cargo"
        ng-options="cg.name for cg in MyCtrl.getCargo().handler.cg">
</select>
```

And cargo looks something like this:

```
this.cg = {
    cgCategory: "",
    cgName: ""
}
```

Both cg and cargo are getting their data from an external json object. It's worth noting that while they have the same exact data and structure, cg and cargo are separate arrays. This is so that selecting an item from the select dropdown doesn't cause the others to disappear.

After a lot of trial and error, I got the code to work. However, I want each item of the select tag to show both the cargo's category, and its given name. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what `MyCtrl.getCargo()` returns..? could you paste the code of it here?

Comment: I think it's `cg.cgName` instead of `cg.name`